# Smooth approximation near a non differentiable point

Tags: polynomials, series-expansion, approximation, differentials

Let $f:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function differentiable for $x>0$ but non differentiable at $x=0$ (for instance $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$)
and $g$ be a polynomial function.
I know how to compute the Taylor series of $f(g(t,x))$ at a point $g(t_0,x_0)>0$.
But I don't know how to construct a differentiable approximation (polynomial) when this point is $0$.

Edit: an approximation of $f$ would be a smooth function $\varphi_N$ (polynomial) such that $f(g(t,x)) = \varphi_N(t,x) + o(t^N,x^N)$.

Are there some works in this direction ?

I read here [How to Approximate at Non-differentiable Point (forced Series Expansion around Branch Cut)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136395/how-to-approximate-at-non-differentiable-point-forced-series-expansion-around-b)
but it doesn't investigate this point.

Comment: That depends very much on the meaning that you associate to the word "approximation".

Comment: Maybe a Pade approximation?

Comment: Maybe ``Needs["FunctionApproximations`"];
MiniMaxApproximation[Sqrt[h], {h, {$MachineEpsilon, 1}, 8, 2}]``

Comment: I am having a look with Pade approximation, I can find a Padé approximation for $f$, does the composition with $g$ will remain a approximation of$f\circ g$ ?

Comment: `PadeApproximant[Sqrt[x],{x,0,{2,2}}]` just returns `Sqrt[x]` and the reason for that is because Mathematica can't evaluate the Series of `Sqrt[x]` at $0$

Comment: Is this somehow Mathematica specific? If not, may be you can get better help in https://math.stackexchange.com/ . May be move the question.

Comment: You cannot approximate $\sqrt{u}$ with polynomial or rational functions if you want the error to be $O(u^n)$ or $o(u^n)$ for a positive integer $n$ as $u\rightarrow0$, because the derivative of the approximant will be finite at $u=0$.  It gets more complicated when you put $g$ in, because for instance, for $g(t,x)=(t^2+x^2)^2$, $\sqrt{g(t,x)} = t^2+x^2$ is a polynomial.

Comment: You can approximate $\sqrt{u}$ over a finite interval $[0,b]$, but the error should be measured with an $L^p$ norm, such as $\mathop{\text{Max}}|\phi(u)-\sqrt{u}|$, where the maximum is over $0 \le u \le b$.